# wifi - meaning of deauth reason codes

Tags: drivers, low-level, wifi

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

```
3 - Deauthenticated because sending STA is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS.
4 - Disassociated due to inactivity.
```

Both sent from a client to the AP, I'm trying to find what triggers them.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a client will authenticate (verification of credentials) and associate (approve to send data in the Service Set) the client must also deauthenticate (credentials are no longer valid) and disassociate (which terminates the connection).